Apps Script functions not saving to global variables & getRange().setValues issues
I am new to apps script / javascript / programming in general.
I am trying to have the user highlight a range of years in a sheet and save the array of years to a global variable yearValues.
I then want to take that array and set those values in a new sheet (successfully created the new sheet) starting at cell B2.
I cant get the yearArr() function to update the yearValues global variable. It always states the variable is undefined.
I am also having difficulty with the getRange and setValues

getRange says its a different size than yearValues

setValues says it can't take yearValues as a parameter


I feel like I am missing something obvious but can't figure it out
code.gs
// DECLARING VARIABLES
let sheet;
let yearValues = [];

// STORE YEAR RANGE INTO AN ARRAY VARIABLE TO OUTPUT INTO NEW SHEET
const yearArr = function () {
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  yearValues = sheet.getActiveRange().getValues();

  return yearValues; 
}



//CREATING A NEW SHEET & INPUT YEARS 
const newSheet = function () {
//CREATING NEW SHEET
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheet.insertSheet('Retention Analysis');

//WRITING YEAR VARIABLES TO CELLS
analysisSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Retention Analysis')

// WRITE VALUES TO STARTING AT CELL B2
analysisSheet.getRange(2,2,1,yearValues.length).setValues(yearValues);

}

index.html code for calling both the yearArr() and newSheet() functions from clicking buttons on client side.
 <button type="button" onclick='analysisSheet()'>Submit</button>

<button type="button" onclick='yearArr()'>Set Range</button>

const storeYearRange = function () {
  google.script.run.yearArr();
}

const analysisSheet = function () {
  google.script.run.newSheet();
}


Apps script is stateless: Stateless vs Stateful You need to pass around data from client to server using google.script.run(preferred) or use properties service on the server.

const analysisSheet = function (yearArr) {
  google.script.run.newSheet(yearArr);
}

const storeYearRange = function () {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(yearArr => analysisSheet(yearArr)).yearArr();
}


Pass the year array:
const newSheet = function (yearArr) {
//....

// WRITE VALUES TO STARTING AT CELL B2
analysisSheet.getRange(2,2,1,yearArr.length).setValues(yearArr);
}

Do note that if yearArr  contains date objects, they're illegal to pass around. You need to  convert it to JSON string on the server using JSON.stringify and then parse back when needed.
